# How come associative law of matrix multiplication won't work when permutation matrices come in. Which is the case for some

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> if $$x=y$$ explain why $$Px=Py$$

I believe this part is very since when we do 
$$P^{-1}Px = P^{-1}Py$$ from here $$x=y$$

But the other part of the question seems much more confusing

> then $$(Px)^T(Py)=x^Ty$$ says that $$P^TP=I$$ for any permutation.

Once we check out permutation matrices it's easy to figure out that YES their transpose is equal to their inverse? This could be derived no matter what order the matrix has right? For ANY permutation matrix...

Okay, but I have no idea how this is possible =

> With $$x=(1,2,3)\ \mbox{ and }\ y=(1,4,2)$$ choose $$P$$ to show that $$(Px)^Ty$$ is not always equal to $$x^T(P^Ty)$$

First of all I thought about finding a $P$ which doesn't have an inverse. Since 
$$P^T=P^{-1}$$ (this is correct right?)

But Permutation matrices are always invertible right, you can always do row exchanges even though some pivots appear to be 0 at the beginning. (No column or row consists of completely zeros.)

And matrices always above the associative law. So I couldn't get how this could be possible. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You're right; if you copied the problem correctly, this is a mistake. $(Px)^\top y=(x^\top P^\top)y=x^\top(P^\top y)$.

Answer (score 0):

a property of the  transposition operation $M\mapsto M^t$ is so:
let $ M$, $N$ be two matrix s.t  $MN$ defined, then $N^tM^t$ is
defined,  $(M^t)^t = M$, and  $(MN)^t = N^tM^t$.

Let $\varphi$  a bilinear form on  a vector space $V$ of dimension
$n$, with bases $A$ and $B$ then the matrix $M$, $M'$ of $\varphi$
respectively in bases $A$ and $B$ are related by the formula $ M'
= P^tMP$ where $P$ is the change base matrix from $A$ to $B$ and
thus the value of $\varphi$ in $ (x, y)$ is  $\varphi(x,
y)=X^tMY=X'^tM'Y'$ where $ X, Y$ are  coordinated vectors
respectively
 of $x$ and $y$ in $A $, also $X', Y'$ those in $B$.

The first point to clarify is that for every square matrix $M$ of
order $n$, and vectors $x$ having $n$ coordinates (that is $x\in V
$ with $dimV=n$)  we have: $(Mx)^t y = (x^tM^t) y = x^tM^ty = x^t
(M^ty)$.

second point a permutation matrix is a matrix $P$ which permutes
the vectors of a same base, in your case    the base is  where
$\varphi$ is the product scalar $(x, y)\mapsto x^ty$  this basis
of which it is expressed this scalar product (positive definite
bilinear form) is an orthonormal basis, so a permutation matrix P
on this basis is a matrix  that switch one  orthonormal basis to
an orthonormal basis, this type of matrix P are characterized by
$p^t = P^{-1}$